# Inset Shadow Text with React Native

Tags: css, react-native, styles

I'd like to reproduce an effet such as :

- https://1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/css3-text/inset-text-css3-text-effect-tutorials.jpg
- https://jsfiddle.net/NeqCC/

With react-native

I did this snack. But i'm not able to implement inner shadow (https://snack.expo.io/rJ_Uzhdrf)

Using

```
textShadowColor: 'grey',
textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
textShadowRadius: 10
```